# Implementing a binary heap using a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, heap, binary-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linked list implementation of Binary Min Heap (Having trouble with manipulation…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518572/linked-list-implementation-of-binary-min-heap-having-trouble-with-manipulation)

Greetings,

I'm having trouble figuring out an algorithm that will give me the location of a tree node in a linked list implementation of a binary heap.  I've implemented a heap using arrays now I want to try using a linked list; Is there a way to find the tree node whose array index would have been i had I used an array to represent the heap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [Michael Springmann implementation](http://www.michaelspringmann.de/programs/algorithms/HeapJava/src/Heap.java)

Answer (score 5):

What's the point? A linked list implementation will be either slower or more complex than an array-based one. If you replace the array with a simple linked list and don't add other structure your insertion time will be O(n) instead of O(log n), and then you could as well just maintain a sorted list in same O(n) complexity.

Comment: A binary heap is not always better. You can implement a heap with an unordered linked list. It'll have `O(1)` insert and `O(n)` delete time complexity for a list of size n. A binary heap is `O(n log n)` for both delete and insert. If you only need to do a small (i.e., constant) number of deletions, a linked list will be the way to go. A good example of this in actual practice is using a heap for Dijkstra's algorithm where you need `|E|` inserts and `|V|` deletemins. In that case, the linked list is definitely better if you have a dense graph, but the binary heap is better for sparse graphs.